# Finding function with specified limits

Tags: limits, functions

I am seeking a function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)\to 1$ as $x\to 0$, and $f(x)\to \alpha>0$ as $x\to \infty$. I thought the function must have a term proportional to $e^{-x}$, but I can't see what the entire function may look like. After repeated failed attempts, I am beginning to wonder if such a function exists. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$
goes to $1$ at $x=0$ and to $0$ at infinity.

Look for 
$$g(x)=af(x)+b$$

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. Looks like it is not possible to have a function which contains $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @Zero Try $ae^{-x}+b$.

Comment: The function $(1-\alpha)e^{-x}+\alpha$ does the job.

Comment: @Peter +1 Thanks a lot. This is the solution to hint given by N.S. in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(x)=\frac{\alpha x+1}{x+1}$$ satisfies $f(0)=1$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=\alpha$$

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. As I wrote in the comment below may be it is not possible to have a function which contains $e^{-x}$.

Comment: I wish I could accept your answer too. But thank you very much for your response.

Comment: No problem, Zero. By the way, I upvoted your question and do not understand the $2$ downvotes.

Comment: It's alright. I shall ignore those downvotes since they didn't state the reason.